# Receiving Installation Error: ApplicationVerificationFailed in Flash Builder for iOS

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder

This is the error I'm getting when I try to install my app on my iPhone.

[image]

**More details**:
It did work at one point. I used a different computer recently, working on a different project and had to create a new certificate. This invalidated my other projects (profiles). I went back to working on the first computer and uploaded the certificate from that one. I recreated the app profiles and downloaded the provisioning files based on that previous certificate. None of that worked. In the end I had to start over from scratch as shown in the answer below.

Comment: <<Details...???  && see [this forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/15299-error-(0xE800003A)-Application-Verification-Failed)

Comment: That is all the details I have. It did eventually work as I'll post below.

Comment: In my case, it was problem with certificate, i was using publishing certificate to run on testing device..

Comment: My app can install on one iPad and not the other.  Both devices have the provisioning profile.  What could be the cause?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally got it to work by starting over from scratch. I think the problem was that when I went to a new computer and uploaded a new certificate I had to revoke the old certificate. It seems that once it's revoked that maybe it can't be used again.

So I recreated my signing certificate, recreated a p12 file from it, recreated (modified) the app profile (making sure to select my certificate again and selected all of my devices again), redownloaded the mobile provisioning file, reselected these in the iOS configuration screen and restarted Flash Builder and it worked again.

I had tried to use a wildcard, "com.myactualdomainhere.*" and I couldn't get that to work but I didn't do all the steps above (I didn't recreate my signing certificate) and if you can't reuse a certificate then that may have been the issue.

So I did all the steps above and used the app name, "com.myactualdomainhere.MyApp" and made sure it matched in the application descriptor file (for AIR apps) com.myactualdomainhere.MyApp.

It would be nice if someday they could simplify this process and give better error messages. Maybe they could verify the different parts along the way, for example, "your certificate is ok, your app profile checks out, but your app id is incorrect."

Also, MilkyWay posted a link to a post that has some [more](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/15299-error-%280xE800003A%29-Application-Verification-Failed) helpful information.

Comment: FYI: A subset of this answer may help - in our case, we had updated an expired certificate without regenerating a provisioning profile.  So all we had to do was open "Provisioning Profiles" in the iOS dev portal, edit, make sure our new certificate was checked, regenerate, and redownload.  We didn't have to redo the whole cert setup.  And we do use a wildcard.

Answer (score 11):

I experienced this error working with code from another vendor. As it turns out, they were trying to compile the IPA with an Entitlements.plist file. I just deleted that block of code (below) and it compiled just fine.

```
<Entitlements>
    <![CDATA[
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <true/>
    ]]>
</Entitlements>
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! ..or at least the two remaining hours left after searching the entire day for what might cause the 'failed to install' and 'ApplicationVerificationFailed' errors.
@Apple: Some decent feedback would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4):

I've just been stuck with this problem this morning, took a while to figure out so thought I'd post incase anyone else has the same issue.

We had a problem adding a device to our provisioning profile, an iPhone 5 on iOS7. It turned out that the application we were using to get the UDID (UDID+) was giving us the wrong UDID. When I used the ID returned by

```
adt -devices -platform ios
```

It worked.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was at matter of unaccepted characters in some embedded folders. Folder names that contained special characters (`æ` `ø` `å` or whitespace) resulted in an  `ApplicationVerificationFailed` error. (Not exactly the most precise error description I have encountered.)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but if anyone else is Googling around and finds this thread and it does NOT fix your issue, I wanted to share my experience on this one.  If you've confirmed that your certificates and provisioning profiles are all good and are still getting this, I determined that you will receive this exact same error if you have your app configured for TESTFLIGHT.  In other words, in your APPNAME-app.xml make sure that the following is commented out within the IOS entitlements section:

```
<key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>
```

Once I commented that out, I was able to resume debugging locally.  Pissed that I spent a day on this, but at least it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if you change your Apple ID password.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that in my Application ID under apple developers, my app wasn't checked for PushNotification, but within my xml application descriptor, I had the entitlments for push notifiaction (aps_development).

Once à removed the APS value from my XML, worked all good.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't compiled in a long time, be sure you set your compilation settings to device testing and make sure you are using your testing provisioning profile. I got this today because my settings were still on app store.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that I was using a .p12 file which was meant for Apple Push Notifications instead of the .p12 file of my Developer certificate..

I used the .p12 I exported from my developer certificate and it works great..!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was incorrect application id problem (different compiled app id then app id I  have defined apple)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this error occurs because of you bin-debug folder.

if that folder has some unknown character or something this error occurs.

I suggest if in that case you have to clean the project or find that file and change it's name

Answer (score 0):

If it was working previously, just restart the flash builder.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests today on test flight with the Entitlements tags. It need to be remove when testing localy or I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Like jbyun94 mentionned, get rid of unknown characters in filenames.

I had files in conflict from dropbox that prevented the app from compiling.

Removed them and everything worked again (though I'd lost a couple of hours :/)