# Adobe Air app greyed on iOS 8.1.2

Tags: ios, air, adobe

I have an app that is built on top of the Adobe Air and run under iOS. The app worked fine. But recently It stopped properly work. The icon of the app is grayed after the installation. I updated Flex & Air SDK to 4.14 and 17 release. I also changed the app id and took certificates from another Apple ID. I added the device to the list of allowed devices as I done before and built ipa-debug package. After install I get app icon greyed. What reason could cause this behavior? What should I check? I spent two days trying to make it work, but with no success.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

There are many informations out there what causes greyed icons on iOS. Some are simple bugs that can be circumvented by a restart of iOS and/or reinstall via iTunes. But I think in your case (and we are talkin AIR here) you should try to read the Console via Xcode (if you can) like suggested [here](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/156538/ios-app-icon-greyed-out-title-stuck-permanently-on-installing#answer-267802).  How you can debug via Xcode is described [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28289/debugging-ios-apps-in-xcode-4-5) in Detail. Feel free to attach more informations about whatever you could receive from that output console.

Comment: Unfortunately, the device's log provided by Xcode is empty...( I don't know  what to do else to make this stuff work, it's really sad for me

Comment: You said you switched the SDK, AppID and certificate. What happens when you reverse all this? Does the Problem still persists even in its vanilla state where it was still runnning? Then it might be a problem in the device with conflicting resources. Have you tried it on another iDevice? Is the Problem persistent over all iOS devices you can get your hands on in vanilla and in the version with the latest changes. What else did you tried to narrow the error down?

Comment: I've made an empty project example, then I used Xcode to create certificate and prov. profile and have the same result. The Xcode created * (asterisk) appid in my dev. profile. If I change appid in my application's descriptor, the app icon on device disappears. Meanwhile I use * as app id while generating new prov. profile. I also tried to build and run the default app from Xcode and it runs perfectly... Adobe Air will make me die.

Comment: Did you know where i breaks? I mean, when you create a new Air-Application, does it compile or does it break? I'm still in the dark what could cause your problem. 
Your initial question stated that i breaks only on AIR 17. Does an empty Project breaks as well or only your app? Does your IDE give you stack-errors? You can give me a empty projekt that breaks for you and I will see if I can compile it.

Comment: Couple minutes ago I just found out the reason. It was my fault as I think on 98%, due to file descriptor contained beta testing entitlements from previous account. I just commented it and app started working. But 2% relate to ITunes that just swallow the error occurred while the install process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081935/receiving-installation-error-applicationverificationfailed-in-flash-builder-for. I could see it in terminal after I made idb work. Before it failed with "itunes library not found" error. Thank you man for your time and support!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you solved it. Sometimes all it takes is someone who listens while one is solving the problem by itself :D