# Getting Libgdx Game in Android Studio to run on iOS device?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, robovm

So Im really stuck right now, I have no idea what to do from here on.. I am trying to run my libgdx game (which runs perfect on desktop and android device) on my iPhone 6. However whenever I try to do that through Android Studio I keep getting this

```
[ERROR] Couldn't start application
org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: ApplicationVerificationFailed
    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher$1.error(AppLauncher.java:1001)
    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.Callbacks.callInstproxyCallback(Callbacks.java:64)

[ERROR] Failed to copy /Users/edwardlim/AndroidStudioGames/SwimFishy/ios/robovm-build/tmp/ROBOVM iOS (Device)/ios/thumbv7/IOSLauncher.app/IOSLauncher to indexed dir /Users/edwardlim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoboVM/Build/Products/IOSLauncher_20150912214441/IOSLauncher.app: Failed to copy full contents from '/Users/edwardlim/AndroidStudioGames/SwimFishy/ios/robovm-build/tmp/ROBOVM iOS (Device)/ios/thumbv7/IOSLauncher.app/IOSLauncher' to '/Users/edwardlim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoboVM/Build/Products/IOSLauncher_20150912214441/IOSLauncher.app/IOSLauncher'
[INFO] [  0%] Beginning installation...
[INFO] [  5%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[INFO] [ 15%] ExtractingPackage
[INFO] [ 20%] InspectingPackage
[INFO] [ 20%] TakingInstallLock
[INFO] [ 30%] PreflightingApplication
[INFO] [ 30%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[INFO] [ 40%] VerifyingApplication
```

So any help at all would be highly appreciated, all the stuff I found online appears outdated most of them or they are using eclipse. The stuff that i have done so far includes paying the $99 for the apple developer stuff and generated a provision profile. I also open the xCode application on my laptop and pressed that "refresh button" and i see the profile under the view details in my account.. So im just curious as to what i need to do to run the app on my phone. FYI, it runs on the ios simulator provided by robovm

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081935/receiving-installation-error-applicationverificationfailed-in-flash-builder-for . Do any of those answers help? iOS has a minefield of app installation permissions.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ApplicationVerificationFailed

Comment: I have tried the solutions but i dont believe im facing the same issue. I was hoping for a list of to do items after you download robovm and how to get it started with android studio and the whole apple developer stuff. I was hoping to find somehting like this but with android studio http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/02/23/Deploying-a-LibGDX-RoboVM-project-to-an-actual-iOS-device.aspx

Comment: This sounds like a question for the RoboVM folks. Do they really download to iOS from Android Studio? Do they have an XCode plugin? That would seem more likely to succeed.

Comment: I am stuck here too. I've tried everything. Nothing works. How hard could it be for libgdx or robovm folks to supply us with a good guide of EXACTLY how is is supposed to look in config files. I had it working once, but something happened and now I just can't get it to work anymore...